# Tikz and/or PGF: Basic collision avoidance with multipart shape nodes and nodes anchored/pinned to nodeparts?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-graphdrawing

I'm trying to create a `tikzpicture` that contains something like what is in the following sketch.

[image]

I've tried numerous ways to use custom nodes within a `graph drawing`-driven layout, but even when "importing" the nodes is successful, the graph drawing doesn't seem to rearrange the nodes (even though no position was specified when I "declared" the nodes).

I don't really need to draw a complex graph, I'd just like to:

- Specify "ballpark zones" (around a coordinate and/or in a direction relative to another node) for some nodes
- Specify stricter positioning for other nodes (i.e., "must be exactly 5mm directly to the right of X other node")
- Have tikz/pgf respect my strict positioning specifications, and adjust the "ballpark zoned" nodes as necessary to avoid collisions

Is there a way to do this? I know I could always just manually position everything but a self-optimizing diagram would be ideal.

Comment: Gut feeling: Maybe tikz is *not* the right tool for that :).

Comment: From this question it is not at all clear (to me) what you are doing. It may help to add a concrete minimal working example that explicitly illustrates your points.

Comment: Probably you didn't process the document with LuaTeX.  Without Lua `graphdrawing` falls back to a very naive algorithm.